# What is a "unexpected EOF during chunk size line" error in Deno?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, server-sent-events, supabase, deno

I'm developing an Edge Function from Supabase locally. It runs on Deno. When I execute the code below, the following error appears:

```
CPU time limit reached. isolate: 16597602940236451129
CPU time used: 560ms
hyper::Error(User(Body), hyper::Error(Body, Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "unexpected EOF during chunk size line" }))
```

This is the code:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts";
import { corsHeaders } from "../_shared/cors.ts";

function fetchArtistPage(artistName: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://www.last.fm/music/" + artistName.replace(" ", "+"));
        const page = await response.text();
        resolve(page);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

serve(async (req) => {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") return new Response("ok", { headers: corsHeaders });

  const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
  const artistsNames = await req.json();
  const body = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      for (const artistName of artistsNames) {
        controller.enqueue(textEncoder.encode("START_OF_JSON "));
        const artistsData = {
          name: artistName,
          page: await fetchArtistPage(artistName),
        };
        controller.enqueue(textEncoder.encode(JSON.stringify(artistsData)));
        controller.enqueue(textEncoder.encode("END_OF_JSON "));
      }
      controller.close();
    },
  });
  return new Response(body, {
    headers: {
      ...corsHeaders,
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    },
  });
});
```

**Context**

The artistsNames variable will hold an array containing a maximum of 50 strings, where each string represent an artist name. I will fetch the artist last.fm page and send it back in the response inside the artistsData object.

When I run this code, the error appears near the 35-40th artist. If I use just 10 artists, the error doesn't appear. I just tried so many things and nothing works. If I just return text and not the page, it works. But if I parse the html page and return the text content of a tag, it doesn't work.

Edit: I have tried using the data and event fields as the Server Side Events documentations tells to do but I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I would think the main problem is "*CPU time limit reached*" - it probably just kills the process at that point and closes the stream, which is why some other process complains about an unexpected EOF.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi! I should have seen that, it was right in front of me haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi mentioned, the real issue is `CPU time limit reached` after which the isolate is destroyed, which triggers the [`Hyper`](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) (Server) error you're seeing, since the server is shutdown.

You can see the Deno Deploy limits here https://deno.com/deploy/docs/pricing-and-limits

> During the initial public beta, the following hard limits apply. **If**
> **any runtime limits are exceeded, all related requests will be**
> **immediately terminated**, and a warning will be logged to the
> deployment’s logs.

---

You could implement a limit/paging mechanism to avoid the timeout since you mention that you don't get the error when fetching 10 artists.

Make your server only return 1-10 artists on each request.

Comment: Thanks, Marcos! It seems so simple now. I was a bit tired and didn't see it as you said. I'm gonna consider the limit/paging mechanism but it would be awesome to do this in a single request. I'm using free tier hosting so each request counts. If the serverless approach doesn't work, I think I'm gonna test using containers. Thanks for the answer!!